# Mourning for a parent for a year

Tags: halacha-theory, mourning-aveilus

Please provide as many different answers as you can on why is aveilus for a parent for a year and all others is only 30 days.

What different heartfelt ideas come to mind?  What are some ideas that chachamim and rabanim shared on this ?

Comment: I wonder if anyone has any other answers ??

Answer (score 6):

R David Brofsky in his [Hilkhot Avelut](https://korenpub.com/products/hilkhot-avelut) p. 192 quotes R Yosef Blau ([Memories of a Giant](http://www.urimpublications.com/memories-of-a-giant-reflections-on-rabbi-dr-joseph-b-soloveitchik-ztl.html)) as explaining R Yosef Soloveitchik was puzzled why there were 12 months of *aveilut* for a parent who had lived a long full life compared to the one of a child, far more devastating, which lasts only 30 days.

R Blau gives a number of answers that he heard from the protagonists themselves during their *shiva* visit to R Soloveitchik

> - the passing of a parent also represents a loss in the chain that extends to Mount Sinai (R Yitzchak Hutner)
> - the *mitzva* of honoring one's parents continues even after their passing and creates the additional time of mourning (R Mordechai
>   Pinchas Teitz)
> - father and mother are the only *halakhic* relationships that cannot be duplicated (R Mordechai Pinchas Teitz)
> - the relationship of dependency between a child and a parent normally decreases over time and may even reverse itself if a parent
>   lives a long life. The sense of loss might be diminished by the
>   infirmity of the aged parent. In order to force the child to reflect
>   back on his total relationship with his parent, including the early
>   years, and acknowledge the enormity of the debt owed to both father
>   and mother, *halakha* requires this extended period of mourning. When
>   a parent loses a child, there is no need for *halakha* to tell him to
>   mourn. It is a natural response. Rather, what is needed is a process
>   that ends, enabling one to go beyond mourning, return to functioning
>   and tend to the other family members (R Soloveitchik himself)